# Find element with BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: automated-testing, python

I'm still learn to code with `python`. I really need help to scrape the element from this website:

https://www.tokopedia.com/craftdale/crossback-apron-hijau-army?src=topads

I want to get Review data (Review Time) from Review container
[image]

This is `HTML` from the site

[image]

I've tried to get the element with this code

```
review = soup.findAll('p',class_='css-oals0c-unf-heading e1qvo2ff8')
```

or

```
review= soup.findAll('p',id_='txtDateGivenReviewFilter0')
```

But the result is that I only get empty data

[image]

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Webscraping is offtopic on this StackExchange, better post on stackoverflow.com and tag it BeautifulSoup and Webscraping. Goodluck.

Comment: Not sure how you crawl, but the website is dynamic, so maybe the content is not there (yet) when you crawl.

Answer (score 1):

Read this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51839937/beautiful-soup-returns-empty-list

The reason for the failure is that when you open that website reviews are not loaded automatically. The reviews are loaded only when you scroll down to review section.

So you have to inspect the netwrok and find the correct url that loads review

ALso try:

Try review = soup.findAll("p",class_="css-oals0c-unf-heading e1qvo2ff8")

or

```
review = soup.findAll("p",attrs={"data-testid"="txtDateGivenReviewFilter0"})
```

data-testid , is a custom attribute and not a id attribute.

as per the documentation custom attribute should be provided as dictionary

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all

> Some attributes, like the data-* attributes in HTML 5, have names that
> can’t be used as the names of keyword arguments:
>
> data_soup = BeautifulSoup('foo!')
> data_soup.find_all(data-foo="value")
>
> ## SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression You can use these attributes in searches by putting them into a dictionary and passing
>
> the dictionary into find_all() as the attrs argument:
>
> data_soup.find_all(attrs={"data-foo": "value"})
>
> ## [foo!] You can’t use a keyword argument to search for HTML’s ‘name’ element, because Beautiful Soup uses the
>
> name argument to contain the name of the tag itself. Instead, you can
> give a value to ‘name’ in the attrs argument:
>
> name_soup = BeautifulSoup('')
> name_soup.find_all(name="email")
>
> ## [] name_soup.find_all(attrs={"name": "email"})
>
> ## []

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like:

```
review = soup.findAll('p',{"class":["css-oals0c-unf-heading", "e1qvo2ff8"]})
```

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725760/beautifulsoup-findall-given-multiple-classes

The attribute `data-testid` is not the same as `id`, it is a custom html attribute. You could try something like:

```
soup.select('p[data-testid="txtDateGivenReviewFilter0"]')
```

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55519595/custom-attributes-in-beautifulsoup/55519978

Comment: The way class is used is correct as per beautifulsoap documentation

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class